# Displaying a scrollable box for editing text in android

Tags: android-layout

I am trying to display a box which has a scrollbar, and that allows the user to type in their inputs. Currently I have a blank (The one with 'this') that accepts multi-line input using the following layout:

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/event_description"
            android:hint="@string/hint_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#02960B"
            android:textSize="14sp" 
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
```

[image: Form showing a line with multi-line input]

Does anyone know how I could display a box with a scroll bar on the side for multi-line input

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the EditText in a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Comment: @bob_d Please accept this answer or upvote it (or both) if it has helped you or answered your question or solved your problem. Thanks!